# Include xml config in java config

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to include this piece of configuration in my Java config (since I just can't figure out how to do java config with jsp-config):

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

I've tried pasting this piece of code into an xml file, and then used @ImportResources to include it into my `class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Apparently, it didn't work. So what is the right way to do this? I use an `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` in place of web.xml

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/) can be helpful in your case.